# Attribute Error in python problems

Tags: python

import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import argparse

class Stitcher:
    def **init**(self):
        # determine if we are using OpenCV v3.X
        self.isv3 = imutils.is_cv3()

```
def stitch(self, images, ratio=0.75, reprojThresh=4.0,
    showMatches=False):
    (imageB, imageA) = images
    (kpsA, featuresA) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageA)
    (kpsB, featuresB) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageB)

    # match features between the two images
    M = self.matchKeypoints(kpsA, kpsB,
        featuresA, featuresB, ratio, reprojThresh)

    if M is None:
        return None

    # apply a perspective warp to stitch the images
    (matches, H, status) = M
    result = cv2.warpPerspective(imageA, H,
        (imageA.shape[1] + imageB.shape[1], imageA.shape[0]))
    result[0:imageB.shape[0], 0:imageB.shape[1]] = imageB

    # check to see if the keypoint matches should be visualized
    if showMatches:
        vis = self.drawMatches(imageA, imageB, kpsA, kpsB, matches,
            status)

        # return a tuple of the stitched image and the
        # visualization
        return (result, vis)

    # return the stitched image
    return result

def detectAndDescribe(self, image):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    if self.isv3:
        orb = cv2.ORB_create()

        (kps, features) = orb.detectAndCompute(image, None)

    # If we are using OpenCV 2.4.X
    else:
        # detect keypoints in the image
        detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("ORB")
        kps = detector.detect(gray)

        # extract features from the image
        extractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("ORB")
        (kps, features) = extractor.compute(gray, kps)

    # convert the keypoints to NumPy arrays
    kps = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kps])

    # return a tuple of keypoints and features
    return (kps, features)

def matchKeypoints(self, kpsA, kpsB, featuresA, featuresB,
    ratio, reprojThresh):
    # compute the raw matches and initialize the list of actual matches
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create("BruteForce")
    rawMatches = matcher.knnMatch(featuresA, featuresB, 2)
    matches = []

    # loop over the raw matches
    for m in rawMatches:
        # ensure the distance is within a certain ratio of each
        # other (i.e. Lowe's ratio test)
        if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
            matches.append((m[0].trainIdx, m[0].queryIdx))

    # computing a homography requires at least 4 matches
    if len(matches) > 4:
        # construct the two sets of points
        ptsA = np.float32([kpsA[i] for (_, i) in matches])
        ptsB = np.float32([kpsB[i] for (i, _) in matches])

        # homography between the two sets of points
        (H, status) = cv2.findHomography(ptsA, ptsB, cv2.RANSAC,
            reprojThresh)

        # return the matches along with the homograpy matrix
        # and status of each matched point
        return (matches, H, status)

    return None

def drawMatches(self, imageA, imageB, kpsA, kpsB, matches, status):
    # initialize the output visualization image
    (hA, wA) = imageA.shape[:2]
    (hB, wB) = imageB.shape[:2]
    vis = np.zeros((max(hA, hB), wA + wB, 3), dtype="uint8")
    vis[0:hA, 0:wA] = imageA
    vis[0:hB, wA:] = imageB

    # loop over the matches
    for ((trainIdx, queryIdx), s) in zip(matches, status):
        # matching if the keypoint is matched
        if s == 1:
            # draw the match
            ptA = (int(kpsA[queryIdx][0]), int(kpsA[queryIdx][1]))
            ptB = (int(kpsB[trainIdx][0]) + wA, int(kpsB[trainIdx][1]))
            cv2.line(vis, ptA, ptB, (240, 255, 100), 1)

    # return the visualization
    return vis



Output:: Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'is_cv3
```

Please check the code and resend the edited code to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you called your python file `imutils.py`? If so, rename it.

Comment: is imutils a package you are installing from pypi or your own utils? assuming it's your own utils @roganjosh comment makes sense...

Comment: Most likely it's the one mentioned here http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/08/10/checking-your-opencv-version-using-python/ , although it's entirely possibly he either is shadowing it, or is using an older version that doesn't have is_cv3 ... you may want to do import imutils; print(dir(imutils)) to see what it has

Comment: Ugh... Sayantan: your edit just made things worse; A) the formatting just got messed up and B) you went from a farily minimal example to something with extraneous code.  I suggest reverting, and also including the output of pip freeze (which will show what version of imutils you are using)

Comment: "Please check the code and resend the edited code to solve the problem." No. What makes you think we should do that? Also, it would be helpful if you could read and respond to comments that have been here for 20 minutes that might already fix your problem. Please take some time to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am using imutils-0.2.tar.gz @Foon

Comment: Hmm... doing git blame on https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blame/master/imutils/convenience.py, it looks like imultils-0.2.2 had is_cv3; I can't tell if 0.2 did not, or just was formatted slightly differently

Comment: So i have to install the latest version of imutils to successfully run it? @ Foon

Comment: I just checked back. You broke the tag to @Foon by putting a space after the '@' so he won't have been notified.

Comment: Sorry by mistake @roganjosh

Comment: So i have to install the latest version of imutils to successfully run it?  @Foon

Comment: I'm not certain but it wouldn't hurt to try to at least upgrade (but again, if you do print(dir(imultils)) that might give a hint what is and isn't available in your version

Comment: When we write the code in spyder that imutils.something then does it show what libraries are installed in the imutils package? @Foon

Answer (score -1):

you can access to the OpenCV version with `cv2.__version__`

```
def is_cv3():
    return cv2.__version__[0] == '3'
```